# Can not get property "userResponse" of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, object, nativescript

I am tryna learn nativescript by building a travia game app.
I have a questions json list like below:

```
var questionsList20 = {"questions" : [{"question":"Taxing a commodity at the production level decreases supply.","correctAnswer":"answerOne","answerOne":"True","answerTwo":"False","answerThree":"Uncertain","answerFour":"None of the above","userResponse":"","explanationTwo":"True","grade":""},{"question":"The circular flow depicts the alternative combination of goods and services an economy \tcan produce at a point in time.","correctAnswer":"answerTwo","answerOne":"True","answerTwo":"False","answerThree":"Uncertain","answerFour":"None of the above","userResponse":"","explanationTwo":"False","grade":""},{"question":"Demand is inelastic if elasticity of demand < 0.","correctAnswer":"answerTwo","answerOne":"True","answerTwo":"False","answerThree":"Uncertain","answerFour":"None of the above","userResponse":"","explanationTwo":"False","grade":""},{"question":"Elasticity of demand measures the percentage change in the quantity demand of a commodity as a result of a given percentage change in price.","correctAnswer":"answerTwo","answerOne":"True","answerTwo":"False","answerThree":"Uncertain","answerFour":"None of the above","userResponse":"","explanationTwo":"False","grade":""}]}
```

to get individual questions i am doing this:

```
questionViewModel.startNewGame = function () {


    for (var i = 0; i < questionViewModel.numberOfQuestions - 1; i++) {
        questionViewModel.test.questions[i].userResponse = "";
        questionViewModel.test.questions[i].grade = "";
    }
}
```

At first it works but later i get the error that cannot set property userResponse of undefined.

i don't know how to solve this. Please help.

Comment: I don't know where come from `questionViewModel.numberOfQuestions`, but I think you don't need to do - 1, because the condition is `i <`..

Comment: What is questionViewModel?

Comment: questionViewModel is the model for the questions view. and numberOfQuestions is the number of questions it contains. @LucasCosta what do you mean by i dont need to do 1? please expantiate.

Comment: I guess the indice is not found, then you only try `for (var i = 0; i < questionViewModel.numberOfQuestions ; i++) {`

Comment: Tried it. Same error.

Comment: can you show what `console.log('question length = ' + questionViewModel.test.questions.length)` outputs ?

Comment: could you provide some more code, where show your `ViewModel`. Just suggest, if `questions` is from type `ObservableArray` you should use `getItem(index)` method to access the element.

Comment: My best guess is that `questionViewModel.numberOfQuestions` and the actual number of items in the array(`questionViewModel.test.questions.length`) are not equal. You can try to `console.log` them before the loop - just for sanity check :)

Comment: Thanks guys, it's actually an issue issue with questionViewModel.numberOfQuestions. there are 3 options to choose from (10, 20, 50). the error does not come up when i use 10 or 20 but when i choose 50 it shows up. So i took a closer look and found out the questionViewModel.numberOfQuestions was not up to 50 it was 47. Hence, the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to initialize an empty question array and push each question like a Question object.

```
questionViewModel.startNewGame = function () {
    questionViewModel.test.questions = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < questionViewModel.numberOfQuestions; i++) {
        questionViewModel.test.questions.push({"userResponse": "", "grade": ""});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alog @Nick lliev it's been fixed